# mem_fun_ref question

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Why is this code resulting in a compiler error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    public:
        void Print(int x)
        {
            cout << x << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    mem_fun_ref<void, X, int>(&X::Print) p;
};
```

**Error**
`main.cpp:18: error: expected ; before p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mem_fun_ref`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/) is a function template, so it does not name a type.

`mem_fun_ref<void, X, int>(&X::Print)` is a function call that returns a value, so it makes no sense that there is a  `p` following it.

The return value of that function call is a `mem_fun1_ref_t<void, X, int>`, in case you were looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you intend to write

```
mem_fun1_ref_t<void, X, int> p(&X::Print);
           ^^^^             ^^^
```

instead? `mem_fun_ref` is not a class template, but a function template.